# x86 assembly - multimodule programming (MASM/TASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

ok so here's the code:

```
assume cs:code, ds:data
data segment
  sname db 'Some Name','$'
  len equ $-sname
  ascii db 'a'-'A'

data ends
code segment
start:
  mov ax,data
  mov ds,ax

  cld
  lea si,sname

  do_this:
    lodsb

    cmp al,61h
    jae lowercase

    uppercase:
      cmp si,len
      je the_end
      jmp continue

    lowercase:
      mov bl,ascii
      sub ax,bx

      mov ds:[si-1],al
      cmp si,len
      je the_end

  continue:
  loop do_this

  the_end:
  mov ax,0000
  lea dx,sname
  mov ah,09h
  int 21h

  mov ax,4c00h
  int 21h

code ends
end start
```

Basically it just converts all lowercase letters of the string 'sname' into uppercase.
My question is, how do i split this code into 2 modules, one of which will handle the string printing part. Specifically, i want an .asm module that handles the string conversion to uppercase, and one that handles :

```
  lea dx,sname
  mov ah,09h
  int 21h
```

I can't seem to find any good tutorials on this so if you could point me towards some, it would be much appreciated, and if not, a simple example of how to put 2 .asm modules together ( what directives are required, etc ) , would be great.

Comment: do you want it to be external?

Comment: yes. I want to have 2 different .asm files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you simply move whatever code and data you want to move to a different assembly file and keep all the segment definitions. And then you add a few declarations with `extrn` and `public`:

file1.asm:

```
code segment

public convert
convert:
  ; code for the convert routine
  ret

code ends
end
```

file2.asm:

```
code segment

extrn convert:near
start:
  ; some code
  call convert
  ; some more code

code ends
end start
```

You might need to formally define subroutines:

```
convert proc
  ; code for the convert routine
  ret
convert endp
```

Comment: ok but what code do i need in file2.asm to tell it to use a string defined in the data segment of file1.asm ? Because in file1.asm i'm converting a string to uppercase, and i want to use the same string(or a copy of it) in file2.asm, and print it on the screen

Comment: You do the same, add `extrn sname:byte near` and `public sname`. Or you could just pass the address of the variable in a register.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: that's what my code is showing, somewhat, I didn't show the pushes in the main but... In the main.asm you could push cx and dx, then as seen in my random.asm `FAR PUBLIC USES CX DX`. The following line - LOWER... - are those variable in random.asm.

Comment: Why do you `call start` in `file2.asm`?? shouldn't you `call convert`?

Comment: @frank17 Fixed now!

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I am having similar problem, in TASM I want to call external procedure from my "main program" file, I tried this like what you suggested but I am getting error 'Undefined symbol procedure_name' where 'procedure_name' is the one where I do 'call procedure_name'. Any ideas?

Comment: Or what do you mean by formally defining subroutines?

Comment: @frank17 I meant the use of `proc` and `endp`. You should ask(=create) a new question.

Comment: I would love to but due to many retards in this forum, my question limit is blockin me

Comment: @frank17 Forgot public? extrn? Forgot to (re)assemble your file(s)? Forgot to mention all of the object files to the linker?

Answer (score 2):

At the top beneath `.MODEL` you would provide:

```
EXTRN     RANDOM:FAR
```

Then:

```
;
          .CODE
MAIN:
          .STARTUP
;
;     
          CALL      RANDOM 
;
;
```

In Random.asm:

```
;
          .CODE   
          ASSUME    DS:RAND_DATA
;
RANDOM    PROC      FAR PUBLIC USES CX DX DS,
                    LOWER:WORD, UPPER:WORD
                                        ;FUNCTION RANDOM(LOWER,UPPER)
                                        ;SAVE REGISTERS (USES LIST)
          PUSHF                         ;SAVE FLAGS
          MOV       AX,SEG RAND_DATA    ;SET DS-REGISTER TO POINT
          MOV       DS,AX               ;TO LOCAL DATA SEGMENT
;
;
          POPF                         ;RESTORE FLAGS

          RET                          ;RETURN (RANDOM)
RANDOM    ENDP                         ;END RANDOM
```

For one thing I'm no master of ASM. So give it a shot and let me know. This is from a working program but I had to do some cutting and pasting and there were multiple procedures so let me know how it works and I'll try my best to work it out.

Comment: I've upvoted both answers since they both helped me understand how things work, however I've selected @AlexeyFrunze 's answer since it seemed somewhat easier to understand to me. Thank you both for your time !

Comment: I'll grant you another one. :)