# How to call a C function from Assembly?

Tags: c, assembly

Here's the entire assembly program:

```
.model small
.stack 256

.code
start:
    call printer
    mov ax, 3       ; store 3 into ax

    mov ah, 76      ; back to DOS
    mov al, 0       ; no errors
    int 21h         ; interupt -> DOS
end start
```

And this is where I define the `C` function `printer`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printer()
{
    printf("Hello!\n");
}
```

When compiling the assembly code, I get an error: `undefined symbol: printer`. In `C` I would do an `#include "file.h"`, how do I achieve the same result here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add something like

```
extern  _printer
```

on the top of your assembly and use call with this name

```
call _printer
```

Correct name of function depends on naming convention of your C compiler. Compiler may add some characters to the C name of the function.

Correct "extern" keyword depends on your assembler and it could be ".extern" or so.

Edit 1:
In Turbo Assembler and for that case with function without parameter, it should be just

```
extrn printer
```

or

```
extrn printer:NEAR
```

I am not familiar with TASM.

Comment: Nice lead, but this assembler (TASM) doesn't have `extern` or `.extern` as a keyword. So I keep getting `Illegal instruction`. Any other ideas?

Comment: @MorganWilde Have you tried `EXTRN`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893969/x86-assembly-multimodule-programming-masm-tasm

Comment: @nrz also according to "Turbo Assembler Version 4.0 Users Guide" so updating the answer.

Comment: @j123b567 Thanks for the update, solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not compilation, it's linking.  You must link (using `ld` if on Unix/Linux) your executable including the object file with the assembly code and the object file with the C code.

Or put your assembly code into your C file using an `"asm"` block.

Comment: I'm using TASM to compile the assembly code, and that's when I get the error. There's a separate executable for linking and I don't even reach that stage.

Comment: Yeah, but I do get an object file from TASM, it's just that it refuses to make that object file with an `undefined symbol`.